# How to code c++ project online in one project [management]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project-management

I'm beginner in C++ programming using visual studio c++. I like to have access to my project codes instantly while programming, something like a project manager. How is this possible in Visual Studio C++ ? I have found `Team Foundation Server` but I have not clue what it is.

Comment: TFS is a centralized version control system as opposed to Git, for example, which is a distributed version control system. If you're already acquainted with Git and not with TFS (which I find to be fairly common),VS2013 has a built-in Git provider (a really nice one in my opinion). For VS2012 you'll need to install one separately.

Comment: I'm familiar with Git. does VS2013 supports Git natively?

Comment: Yes, that's what the built-in Git provider is for. VS2012 can install one trivially with a package.

Comment: thanks much Assorted Trailmix

Comment: I'm going to turn this into an answer for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS is a centralized version control system as opposed to Git, for example, which is a distributed version control system.

If you're already acquainted with Git and not with TFS (which I find to be fairly common),VS2013 has a built-in Git provider (a really nice one in my opinion). For VS2012 you'll need to install one separately, it's a package.